# Otimizar exclusão de 700 mil registros de uma tabela MySQL

Tags: windows, mysql

Olá, estou precisando com urgência de excluir 700 mil registros em uma tabela com pouco mais de 2 milhões. Porém, em testes no servidor do escritório está demorando horas pois preciso de filtrar um campo e vou precisar de fazer esse tipo de exclusão em outros clientes também, poderiam me ajudar?

**Edit1:**
@AndersonCarlosWoss, tenho 24 colunas que são:
    `APT_ID int(11)`
    `APT_IDPRODUCAO int(11)`
    `APT_TIPO   varchar(10)`
    `APT_HRINICIAL  varchar(5)`
    `APT_HRFINAL    varchar(5)`
    `APT_IDCLIENTE  int(11)`
    `APT_IDPRODUTO  int(11)`
    `APT_PRODUTIVIDADE  decimal(5,2)`
    `APT_PRODUTIVIDADEFAIXA decimal(5,2)`
    `APT_QUANTIDADE decimal(8,2)`
    `APT_IDMOTIVO   int(11)`
    `APT_IDCOMPONENTE   int(11)`
    `APT_HRPRODUTIVA    decimal(15,10)`
    `APT_HRDISPONIVEL   decimal(15,10)`
    `APT_IDOPERACAO int(11)`
    `APT_IDTAXA int(11)`
    `APT_HORAS  decimal(15,10)`
    `APT_IDDETALHEPARADA    int(11)`
    `APT_HRINICIOAPT    varchar(5)`
    `APT_HRFIMAPT   varchar(5)`
    `APT_PRODUTIVIDADEZERO  varchar(1)`
    `APT_HRDISPONIVELFAIXA  decimal(5,2)`
    `APT_HRPRODUTIVAFAIXA   decimal(15,10)`
    `APT_IDLEITURAHISTORICO int(11)`
A coluna que preciso usar é a 
    **APT_IDCLIENTE**

**Edit2:** Não posso criar tabela nova pois uso as chaves primárias da tabela atual.

Comment: E qual é a estrutura da tabela? Qual é a SQL que deseja otimizar?

Comment: Avalie se não é mais fácil copiar os registros que deseja manter para uma cópia auxiliar de sua tabela, dar um DROP TABLE em sua tabela original e renomear a cópia auxiliar para o nome correto. Pode ser que seja necessário eliminar eventuais constraints e recria-las na nova tabela.

Comment: Não posso fazer essa opção de insert, porque eu uso as chaves primárias dessa tabela que estou precisando excluir os registros

Comment: @GabrielCardoso Informações devem estar na pergunta, não nos comentários. Existe o botão [edit] que te permite fazer isso.

Comment: É a primeira vez que faço pergunta aqui, logo eu não sei usar de forma correta, obrigado pela informação kk

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi esta sua consideração sobre a existência de chave primária impedir que você copie os registros que não serão excluídos para uma nova tabela.

Comment: Então, eu quis dizer que eu uso os IDs da tabela referida (tabela Apontamento) para gravar em outras tabelas, logo, se eu inserir os dados (que eu desejo manter) em outra tabela, as chaves serão refeitas

Comment: A não ser que eu desabilite o auto incremento